# Using Create Fishnet and Project in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, vector-grid

When I try to run the model below, the Create Fishnet tool creates a huge grid that totally ignores the extent input (BLOCK_Project1). It's nowhere near the extent input either.

[image]

If I click on the Project tool and run it independently, then do the same with the Create Fishnet tool once the Project tool is shaded, it works and gives me this.

[image]

I just can't seem to run it all at once and get the results I'm looking for. Whenever I do, I get this for the fishnet.

[image]

Any idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: I think you are showing us too much of your model.  A test model without the two Intersect and Multipart To Singlepart tools should suffice to focus your question on what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: Something to do with dataframe projection.

Comment: Recalculating the output of **projected data's** extent might help, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/recalculate-feature-class-extent.htm, if you are using ArcGIS10.4+ and >Basic licence. If not, creating a copy of your feature class might help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm using a basic license. I figured out the issue though. I thought having an extent in the fishnet tool would auto calculate the number for the total grid rows, but I guess it didn't. I just had to throw a zero into those parameters and it now works. Thanks for the help.